# Search the website for Address values

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, web-scraping

I have been scratching my head on how to tackle this dilemma of mines for a while now. I have a Address column in my csv file, which contains list of Addresses. I want to be able to direct Python to search the website designated below with the individual address values in the csv file and save the results into a new csv file.

```
import csv
import requests

with open('C:/Users/thefirstcolumn.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Address'])

website = requests.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')

writer = csv.writer(open('thematchingresults.csv', 'w'))

print website.content
```

For example:

One of the address value I have in the csv file:

```
6525 Mountain Sky Rd
```

returns three rows of data when I manually paste the address in the search box. How can I tell Python to search for each one of the addresses in the csv file on the website and save the results for each one of the addresses in a new csv file. How can I accomplish this mountainous task?

Comment: What aren't you able to do?

Comment: I need assistance on how to direct Python to search for each one of the address column values one by one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request module downloads static HTML pages from the website. You cannot interact with Javascript

You need to use [Selenium](http://www.marinamele.com/selenium-tutorial-web-scraping-with-selenium-and-python) to interact with the website

For example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')
#read in addresses
with open('file.csv','r') as f:
    adresses = f.readlines()

# use css selectors to locate search field
for address in adresses:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').clear()       
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').send_keys(address)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_btnSearch').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    # JS injected HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    # extract relavant info from the soup 
    # and save to your new csv here
```

Comment: Thanks Tobey, I tried Selenium but from my understanding, Selenium only opens a browser and automates it. I do not think it can actually search for each one of the address column values one by one in the search box.

Comment: I'll extend my answer to explain

Comment: Thanks Tobey, this script does a heck of a job but it does not save the results for the addresses in the csv file. How can that be implemented?

Comment: You need to use a html parser to extract the info you need from the page source. I suggest Beautiful soup. I'll let you figure out this one

Comment: Thanks Tobey for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do a `POST` request for each value you have in the csv file. For example, to search for "6525 Mountain Sky Rd" at https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx, you can look at the developer console to see what POST params it is giving. For example:

[image]

You can use something like `requests` and pass the header values and form data, or you could use something like `casper` or `selenium` to emulate the browser.

Comment: How can selenium be viable here? I have used it in the past and, from my understanding, in a nutshell it automates a web scraping process.

Comment: @PLearner the other answer gives a very good explanation of it. Let me know if that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: The script does a heck of a job but it does not save the results for the addresses in the csv file. How can that be implemented?